# Pulling Last Two Dates PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database which is updated randomly. I'm trying to pull entries by the latest date. This part is simply and I can do it with ease. However, I want to pull the two latest dates.

Example; If my last update was 2015-06-22 and the one before than was 2015-06-12 and the one before then was 2015-06-02. I would want to pull 2015-06-22 and 2015-06-15.

I would use a LIMIT 2, however, there are an unknown amount of items that may have the same date attached.

I haven't tried anything other than the LIMIT 2. After some research, I wasn't able to find anything to reference.

**Update**

I used SELECT DISTINCT to get the desired results.

Comment: Do you use `ORDER BY` in your query?

Comment: Are you ordering on a datetime?

Comment: So, what is the issue then? Do you need to get all of the listings for the date?

Comment: There are multiple entries with that same date, this makes the LIMIT option not work so well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT dates FROM table ORDER BY dates DESC LIMIT 2`

Will give you the latest 2 dates in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a column set to id, that is auto incremented, and do my query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 2
```

Crap McAdam you beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest two dates using LIMIT, like you mentioned:

```
SELECT latestDates
FROM myTable
ORDER BY dateColumn DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

And you can join that to your original table to only select rows that occur on those two dates:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
   SELECT latestDates
   FROM myTable
   ORDER BY dateColumn DESC
   LIMIT 2) tmp ON tmp.latestDates = m.dateColumn;
```